# How to programmatically control/get JUnit view while devloping Eclipse plug-in?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I want to have control over the **JUnit view** programmatically in order to add custom options over each test case method by **right clicking**.

As now when I right click on a particular test case method, I get options like "Go to File, Run, Debug" etc. I want to add my own option there and handle it programmatically. I have not found any posts regarding this and need help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am afraid, the context menu(s) of the *JUnit* view are not extensible.

In order to show or hide the *JUnit* view itself, you can use `findView()`, `showView()`, and `hideView()` declared in `IWorkbenchPage`. To get the active workbench page, use `PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage()`.

The view id of the *JUnit* view is `org.eclipse.jdt.junit.ResultView`